# UML Class diagram confusion

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am learning how to draw a UML class diagram and after reading a few tutorials, I am still confused about the appropriate usages of **Association type** (The clear diamond and black diamond). I understand their usages but I haven't got a very concrete understanding on when to use them and when not to.

For example in the sample class diagram below, I would have thought that if **Customer** does not exist, the **Order** will be gone too but an association diamond was not being used.

Hope someone can provide me with more explaination/examples on the usages of association types.

Thanks.

[image: Sample ordering class diagram]

Comment: There are hundreds of UML examples/tutorials online... just sayin'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An association links one class to another to indicate a relation between them. For example, you have an association between `Customer` and `Order` which (with no further information) indicates that:

1. A customer can have an order or maybe several orders,
2. An order can belong to a customer or maybe shared by several customers.

The diagram in your question gives an additional info: there is one and only one customer by order, and zero or more orders by customer, so the rules become:

1. A customer have zero or more orders,
2. An order belongs to one and one only customer.

While aggregation is used in the association between `Order` and `OrderDetail`, it's not used in the association between `Customer` and `Order`. This is done to indicate the life cycle dependency. If an instance of the `Order` is destroyed, all instances of `OrderDetail` inside it would be destroyed too; on the other hand, the instances of `Order` are independent of the life cycle of the `Customer` instance, thus no aggregation here.

This doesn't mean that an order can exist without a customer: the 1 ↔ 0..* association explicitly forbids the orders which have no customers. The difference between a 1 ↔ 0..* association and the aggregation really happens on life cycle level.